# Count duplicate records

Tags: php, mysql

Suppose I have a table named studens.

[image: students table]

I want to count how many students who received duplicated scores at least 2 times.
Please help me, thanks.

The result that I expect is: Jonh have 100 score 2 times, James have 80 scores 2 times, Julia has 50 scores 2 times. So the amount of students who receive duplicated score at least 2 times is 3 (Jonh, Jam, and Julia).

Comment: Please edit your question and show the results that you are expecting.

Comment: Sidenote: This may come in handy `UPDATE table SET NAME = REPLACE(NAME,'Jonh','John')` and `UPDATE table SET SUBJECT = REPLACE(SUBJECT,'Phisics','Physics')` ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select count(*) from
(
    select name
    from your_table
    group by name, score
    having count(*) > 1
) x
```

Comment: **GROUP BY name, score**: the criteria is not to have two entries on the same subject, but to have the same scores on whatever subjects.

Comment: thanks for you help. would you please tell me what does x at the end mean ?

Comment: @TapiYuki: You need to give every subselect a name. I chose `x` as alias name.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the edit, your query would be:

```
select distinct name
from students
group by name, score
having count(*) > 1;
```

You could see the scores and counts by doing:

```
select name, score, count(*)
from students
group by name, score
having count(*) > 1;
```

By the way, the first query is one of the very, very few times where `select distinct` is appropriate with a `group by`.  I think the second query provides more information, though.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a student has only one score per subject (that is, `name, subject` is unique):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t1.name)
FROM scores t1
    INNER JOIN scores t2
    ON t1.name = t2.name
    AND t1.subject <> t2.subject
    AND t1.score = t2.score
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b778e/1)**